# Make CardMedia Images fit its content in MUI 5

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, material-ui

I want my images to fully fit the CardMedia. Yet since they are of different heights and widths, some of them get cut like so:

[image]

Also upon resizing, some images get cut as well:

[image]

This is the code for the CardMedia part:

```
   <Card
      raised
      sx={{
        maxWidth: 280,
        margin: "0 auto",
        padding: "0.1em",
      }}
    >
      <CardMedia
        component="img"
        height="250"
        image={product.img_urls[0]}
        alt={product.name}
        title={product.name}
        sx={{ padding: "1em 1em 0 1em" }}
      />
      // Other Content
    </Card>
```

**Overall, I want to achieve something like this but with all the cards in the same height and width:**

[image]

***Is there any way I can fix this or do I need to resize each image individually?***

Comment: Looks like a possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/55272024

Comment: @Jack465I I had already checked that out to no avail.

Answer (score 13):

You need to make your pictures to fill their layouts, AND keep their aspect ratio.
The best way is to set their ["object-fit"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) css property to "contain".
Try this:

```
<Card
  raised
  sx={{
    maxWidth: 280,
    margin: "0 auto",
    padding: "0.1em",
  }}
>
  <CardMedia
    component="img"
    height="250"
    image={imageNetwork}
    alt={"alt"}
    title={"titleasdasdsada"}
    sx={{ padding: "1em 1em 0 1em", objectFit: "contain" }}
  />
  // Other Content
</Card>
```

Answer (score -3):

Try this

```
parent-image-element {
 width: 100px;
}

image {
 width: 100%;
 max-height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Comment: This answer doesn't contain any explanation as to how it solves the problem. It also seems like it doesn't actually solve the problem. Answers are more useful over time if they contain explanations.

Comment: Sorry to disappoint. I'm new here and will consider your comment in the future. I just wrote the code that I use.